# Grouping array of objects by multiple properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of notifications that I want to group by certain conditions (like facebook's notifications)

```
var data = [
    { id: 1, type: 'shop.follower', by: { id: 2, name: 'User B', }, in: null, read_at: '2021-01-03 10:15:43', created_at: '2020-08-02 05:21:20' },
    { id: 2, type: 'product.liked', by: { id: 2, name: 'User B' }, in: { id: 1, ... }, read_at: '2021-01-03 10:15:43', created_at: '2020-08-02 05:24:45' },
    { id: 3, type: 'product.commented', by: { id: 3, name: 'User C' }, in: { id: 1, ... }, read_at: '2021-02-20 20:01:39', created_at: '2021-02-19 16:21:43' },
    { id: 4, type: 'product.liked', by: { id: 4, name: 'User D' }, in: { id: 1, ... }, read_at: '2021-03-29 15:14:21', created_at: '2021-03-28 08:11:50' },
    { id: 5, type: 'product.liked', by: { id: 3, name: 'User C' }, in: { id: 1, ... }, read_at: null, created_at: '2021-03-28 08:12:24' },
    { id: 6, type: 'shop.follower', by: { id: 5, name: 'User E' }, in: null, read_at: null, created_at: '2021-05-23 10:02:21' },
    { id: 7, type: 'shop.follower', by: { id: 3, name: 'User C' }, in: null, read_at: null, created_at: '2021-07-18 10:31:12' },
    { id: 8, type: 'comment.replied', by: { id: 4, name: 'User D' }, in: { id: 6, ... }, read_at: null, created_at: '2021-07-24 08:34:25' },
]
```

Let's say I want to group by date in descending order

So I have this code:

```
function sortByDate(array, desc = true) {
    if (desc === false) {
        // Ascending order
        return array.sort((a, b) => {
            if (new Date(a.created_at) > new Date(b.created_at)) {
                return 1
            } else {
                return -1
            }

            return 0
        })
    }

    // Descending order
    return array.sort((a, b) => {
        if (new Date(a.created_at) < new Date(b.created_at)) {
            return 1
        } else {
            return -1
        }

        return 0
    })
}
```

So now we have array like this:

```
[
    { id: 8, type: 'comment.replied', by: { id: 4, name: 'User D' }, in: { id: 6, ... }, read_at: null, created_at: '2021-07-24 08:34:25' },
    { id: 7, type: 'shop.follower', by: { id: 3, name: 'User C' }, in: null, read_at: null, created_at: '2021-07-18 10:31:12' },
    { id: 6, type: 'shop.follower', by: { id: 5, name: 'User E' }, in: null, read_at: null, created_at: '2021-05-23 10:02:21' },
    { id: 5, type: 'product.liked', by: { id: 3, name: 'User C' }, in: { id: 1, ... }, read_at: null, created_at: '2021-03-28 08:12:24' },
    { id: 4, type: 'product.liked', by: { id: 4, name: 'User D' }, in: { id: 1, ... }, read_at: '2021-03-29 15:14:21', created_at: '2021-03-28 08:11:50' },
    { id: 3, type: 'product.commented', by: { id: 3, name: 'User C' }, in: { id: 1, ... }, read_at: '2021-02-20 20:01:39', created_at: '2021-02-19 16:21:43' },
    { id: 2, type: 'product.liked', by: { id: 2, name: 'User B' }, in: { id: 1, ... }, read_at: '2021-01-03 10:15:43', created_at: '2020-08-02 05:24:45' },
    { id: 1, type: 'shop.follower', by: { id: 2, name: 'User B', }, in: null, read_at: '2021-01-03 10:15:43', created_at: '2020-08-02 05:21:20' },
]
```

Now that our array is sorted, I created a function:

```
// https://www.tutorialspoint.com/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript
function groupByProperty(array, property) {
    return array.reduce((acc, object) => {
        const key = object[property]

        if (! acc[key]) {
            acc[key] = []
        }

        acc[key].push(object)

        return acc
    }, {})
}
```

Then, I run this code

```
Object.values(groupByProperty(data, 'type'))
```

Which return:

```
[
    [
        { id: 8, type: 'comment.replied', by: { id: 4, name: 'User D' }, in: { id: 6, ... }, read_at: null, created_at: '2021-07-24 08:34:25' }
    ],
    [
        { id: 7, type: 'shop.follower', by: { id: 3, name: 'User C' }, in: null, read_at: null, created_at: '2021-07-18 10:31:12' },
        { id: 6, type: 'shop.follower', by: { id: 5, name: 'User E' }, in: null, read_at: null, created_at: '2021-05-23 10:02:21' },
        { id: 1, type: 'shop.follower', by: { id: 2, name: 'User B', }, in: null, read_at: '2021-01-03 10:15:43', created_at: '2020-08-02 05:21:20' }
    ],
    [
        { id: 5, type: 'product.liked', by: { id: 3, name: 'User C' }, in: { id: 1, ... }, read_at: null, created_at: '2021-03-28 08:12:24' },
        { id: 4, type: 'product.liked', by: { id: 4, name: 'User D' }, in: { id: 1, ... }, read_at: '2021-03-29 15:14:21', created_at: '2021-03-28 08:11:50' },
        { id: 2, type: 'product.liked', by: { id: 2, name: 'User B' }, in: { id: 1, ... }, read_at: '2021-01-03 10:15:43', created_at: '2020-08-02 05:24:45' }
    ],
    [
        { id: 3, type: 'product.commented', by: { id: 3, name: 'User C' }, in: { id: 1, ... }, read_at: '2021-02-20 20:01:39', created_at: '2021-02-19 16:21:43' }
    ],
]
```

I want to group these notifications by these categories:

1. Same `type` (I already covered this in my function `groupByProperty()`)
2. Same `in: { id: ... }` Except for `type: shop.follower`
3. If #1 and #2 were true, check for similar objects with `created_at: ...` date interval between 10 minutes
4. If we have a case like #3 (multiple), if one among it has `read_at` = null, then it will be an unread notification, get the latest (newest) date

> In `id: 4` and `id: 5`, interval between timestamp are less than 10 minutes, so I want it to group as one

**example EXPECTED OUTPUT**:

```
[
    [
        { by: {id: 4, name: "User D"}, created_at: "2021-07-24 08:34:25", id: 8, in: {id: 6}, read_at: null, type: "comment.replied" }
    ],
    [
        { by: {id: 3, name: "User C"}, created_at: "2021-07-18 10:31:12", id: 7, in: null, read_at: null, type: "shop.follower" }
    ],
    [
        { by: {id: 5, name: "User E"}, created_at: "2021-05-23 10:02:21", id: 6, in: null, read_at: null, type: "shop.follower" }
    ],
    [
        { by: {id: 3, name: "User C"}, created_at: "2021-03-28 08:12:24", id: 5, in: {id: 1}, read_at: null, type: "product.liked" },
        { by: {id: 4, name: "User D"}, created_at: "2021-03-28 08:11:50", id: 4, in: {id: 1}, read_at: "2021-03-29 15:14:21", type: "product.liked" }
    ],
    [
        { by: {id: 3, name: "User C"}, created_at: "2021-02-19 16:21:43", id: 3, in: {id: 1}, read_at: "2021-02-20 20:01:39", type: "product.commented" }
    ],
    [
        { by: {id: 2, name: "User B"}, created_at: "2020-08-02 05:24:45", id: 2, in: {id: 1}, read_at: "2021-01-03 10:15:43", type: "product.liked" }
    ],
    [
        { by: {id: 2, name: "User B"}, created_at: "2020-08-02 05:21:20", id: 1, in: null, read_at: "2021-01-03 10:15:43", type: "shop.follower" }
    ],
]
```

**example IN BROWSER**:

```
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| - (UNREAD) User D replied to your comment .....,   2021-07-24 08:34:25       |
| - (UNREAD) User C start follow your shops .....,   2021-07-18 10:31:12       |
| - (UNREAD) User E start follow your shops .....,   2021-05-23 10:02:21       |
| - (UNREAD) User C and D liked your product .....,  2021-03-28 08:12:24       | <= (Please pay attention)
| - (READ) User C commented on your product .....,   2021-02-19 16:21:43       |
| - (READ) User B liked your product .....,          2020-08-02 05:24:45       |
| - (READ) User B start follow your shops .....,     2020-08-02 05:21:20       |
```

This is the code I tried to `find interval between 10 minutes`

```
function inRangeBetween(val, min, max) {
    if (val >= min && val <= max) {
        return true
    }

    return false
}

var startingPoint = { min: 0, max: 0, type: null },
    newData = []

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (startingPoint.min < 1
        && startingPoint.max < 1
        && startingPoint.type === null) {
        console.log('Starting point')
        var start = new Date(data[i].created_at)
        startingPoint.min = start.getTime()
        startingPoint.max = start.getTime() + (10 * 60000)
        startingPoint.type = data[i].type
        newData[data[i].type] = []
    } else {

        // startingPoint has values
        if (inRangeBetween(new Date(data[i].created_at).getTime(), startingPoint.min, startingPoint.max
            && data[i].type === startingPoint.type) {
            console.log(`Pushing new object to key ${data[i].type}`)
            newData[data[i].type].push(data[i])
        } else {
            // Set new values for startingPoint, and start again comparing
            console.log('Starting point values changes')
            startingPoint.min = new Date(data[i]).getTime()
            startingPoint.min = new Date(data[i]).getTime() + (10 * 60000)
            startingPoint.type = data[i].type
            newData[data[i].type] = []
            newData[data[i].type].push(data[i])
        }
    }
}

// Not working
```

How to achieve this? (Stuck in this problem for 5 days)

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you only struggle with ```I don't know how to group object that has date gap interval between 10 minutes```, you should only give people the necessary example data and ask for an expected output for it. Of course, you should provide what have you done so far and people may help you with your approach as well.

Comment: what do you mean with "*find gap between 10 minutes*"? please add the wanted result.

Comment: @ChristianDelvianto, i do not understand. anyway. by looking to the answers, some more people look like not how to answer this ... it is up to you to shed light on.

Comment: @NinaScholz I just updated my question, please check **example EXPECTED OUTPUT**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```js
var data = [
    { id: 1, type: 'shop.follower', by: { id: 2, name: 'User B', }, in: null, read_at: '2021-01-03 10:15:43', created_at: '2020-08-02 05:21:20' },
    { id: 2, type: 'product.liked', by: { id: 2, name: 'User B' }, in: { id: 1 }, read_at: '2021-01-03 10:15:43', created_at: '2020-08-02 05:24:45' },
    { id: 3, type: 'product.commented', by: { id: 3, name: 'User C' }, in: { id: 1 }, read_at: '2021-02-20 20:01:39', created_at: '2021-02-19 16:21:43' },
    { id: 4, type: 'product.liked', by: { id: 4, name: 'User D' }, in: { id: 1 }, read_at: '2021-01-03 10:15:43', created_at: '2021-03-28 08:11:50' },
    { id: 5, type: 'product.liked', by: { id: 3, name: 'User C' }, in: { id: 1 }, read_at: null, created_at: '2021-03-28 08:12:24' },
    { id: 6, type: 'shop.follower', by: { id: 5, name: 'User E' }, in: null, read_at: null, created_at: '2021-05-23 10:02:21' },
    { id: 7, type: 'shop.follower', by: { id: 3, name: 'User C' }, in: null, read_at: null, created_at: '2021-07-18 10:31:12' },
    { id: 8, type: 'comment.replied', by: { id: 4, name: 'User D' }, in: { id: 6 }, read_at: null, created_at: '2021-07-24 08:34:25' }
]

function sortByDate(array, desc = true) {
    if (desc === false) {
        // Ascending order
        return array.sort((a, b) => {
            if (new Date(a.created_at) > new Date(b.created_at)) {
                return 1
            } else {
                return -1
            }

            return 0
        })
    }

    // Descending order
    return array.sort((a, b) => {
        if (new Date(a.created_at) < new Date(b.created_at)) {
            return 1
        } else {
            return -1
        }

        return 0
    })
}

function groupByProperties(array, properties) {
    return Object.values(array.reduce((acc, object) => {
        const key = properties.reduce((acc, property) => {
          return acc + (object[property] ? JSON.stringify(object[property]) : '')
        }, '')

        if (! acc[key]) {
          acc[key] = []
        }

        acc[key].push(object)

        return acc
    }, {}))
}

function groupByInterval(data, interval) {
  var group;
  
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(1 < data[i].length) {
      
      var max_date = new Date(data[i][0].created_at);
      
      for(var j = data[i].length - 1; 0 < j; j--) {
        var next_date = new Date(data[i][j].created_at)
        
        if(interval < max_date - next_date) {
           if(!group) {
             group = i + 1;
             data.splice(group, 0, [])
           }
           
           data[group].splice(0, 0, data[i][j])
           data[i].splice(j, 1)
        };
      };
      
      if(group) {
         return groupByInterval(data, interval)
      };
    }
    
    data[i].sort((a, b) => {
      if(!a.read_at) {
        return -1
      }
      
      if(!b.read_at) {
        return 1
      }
      
      return 0
    })
  }
  
  data.sort((a, b) => new Date(b[0].created_at) - new Date(a[0].created_at))

  return data
}


sortByDate(data)

//1. Same type
//2. Same in: { id: ... } (Except for type: shop.follower)
data = groupByProperties(data, ['type', 'in'])

//3. If #1 and #2 true, check for similar objects with created_at: ... date gap between 10 minutes
//4. If we have a case like #3 (multiple), if one among it has read_at = null, then it unread notification, then get the latest (newest) date
data = groupByInterval(data, 1000 * 60 * 10) //10min

console.log(data)
```

- `groupByProperties()` is based on `groupByProperty()`, but accepts multiple properties for grouping (categories 1 and 2). It checks whether the value of the property is falsy (such as `null`), excluding it from grouping criteria if so.
- `groupByInterval()` added to separate groups according to a specified interval in milliseconds (categories 3 and 4). It then sorts the groups according to `read_at` being falsy, so that objects with `read_at == null` appear first in each group. It then sorts across groups to achieve the order in the expected result.

Comment: hi @sbgib, thanks for the answer, but it seems the order of notifications by `User B` is wrong, in my **example EXPECTED OUTPUT**, all notifications from `User B` are in lowest order, can we fix it?

Comment: @Gwein ok, it should match the expected output now :)

Comment: okay, thank you for the fix, i'm gonna try your answer now, a moment pls

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, you helped me a lot, if there is any chance that I stumbled on an error using this code, would you please help me? once again, thanks for this answer

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it worked for you! I would fix an issue in the answer to the extent that it correctly answered the original question.

Comment: hi @sbgib, are you busy? I need some improvement with this code, if you don't mind, I will post new question about it

Answer (score 1):

Mr.sbgib is absolutely correct, but i just modified sortByDate function to a little short as follows to reduce duplicate codes,

```
function sortByDate(array, desc = true) {
  return array.sort((a, b) => {
     var compare = new Date(a.created_at) < new Date(b.created_at);
     return (desc == true) ? ((compare == true) ? 1 : -1) : ((compare == false) ? 1 : -1);
  })
}
```